# The repository xxx in project xxx could not be retrieved. Verify the name and credentials being used

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to extend a template on a Azure DevOps pipeline which exists on a repository hosted on Azure Devops. Code looks like below.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: git
      name: otherProject/repositoryXYZ
      ref: main

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    values:
    - "UAT"
    - "Production"
    default: "UAT"

trigger:
- none

pr: none

extends:
   template: folder/template.yml@devops
   parameters:
     environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
```

When I deploy this pipeline on the same project on which repository repositoryXYZ exists, I get a successful run.

For example I have a **project A** which holds 5 pipelines. One of the pipelines is the above and can download the repository and run successfully. This pipeline exists in project A where repositoryXYZ  is located.

When I deploy the same pipeline from a different project **project B** within the same Azure Devops organization, I get the below error.

```
/azure-repo.yml: The repository DevOps in project f1809f72 could not be retrieved. Verify the name and credentials being used.
```

The id of the project on the logs is for **project B**. (f1809f72).

- I tried to alter DevOps repository permissions and to append project
  build collection administrators full access. (repositoryXYZ)
- Then I tried to place the repository on github and I got the same
  issue (added a PAT and changed the directories for the repository)
- I also tried to edit project settings and deactivate the limit jobs
  options. (all limit job aithorization settings have been deactivated for both projects)

Do I miss something? How can I use my pipeline to extend the template which will be downloaded from an Azure Devops repository of another project within the same devops organization?

The pipeline cannot start running at all, so I guess something should be wrong with the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was the referencing repository on the `template.yml` file. On the build pipeline I was pointing the correct repository, but on the template I was pointing a false one that could not be retrieved. I corrected that and I was able to trigger the pipeline.

Comment: could you please post the entire correct .yml file?

Comment: The main pipeline remains as shown and in the referenced `folder/template.yml@devops` pipeline you should need to check the  `resources` in terms of git repository.